# Need to print Access 2010 report without printer prompt

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have this macro built in Access 2010 which will open a report and prompt for a printer selection.  I have it defaulted in the report so I want to skip the printer prompt but can't figure out how to do it.

```
Function OpenReport()
```

On Error GoTo OpenReport_Err

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Results", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrintPreview
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrintSelection
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCloseDatabase
```

OpenReport_Exit:
    Exit Function

OpenReport_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume OpenReport_Exit

End Function

In 2007 there was a print option that did automatically print with no prompt but I can't figure out how exactly to recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The proper line is:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Results", , "", "", acNormal
```

I didn't need the view report parameter.